# jqgrid current row selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i am using this method me return last selected row and i want current selected row.

//JavaScript

```
$.subscribe('cellselect', function(event, data) {   
var sel_id = jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');      
alert(sel_id); 
});
```

//JQgrid event

```
onCellSelectTopics="cellselect"
```

In the Documentation says: "selrow: string   This option is readonly. It contains the id of the **last** selected row". [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

Answer (score 0):

The `selrow` option *will* retrieve the currently selected row in the grid. Are you running into trouble when using this option in your application code?

For what it's worth, if you did want to get the ID of the previously selected row then you would have to add additional code to your application.

Answer (score -1):

selrow will return the currently selected row index if you are not using paging. If paging is used it will return null.

See [this link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) for more information.